# mongodb aggregate query not using index sort

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

hi my document example as below.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee2234fde52e50d9520f6d7"), 
    "ClientMessageId" : "EAAB38DD88551BF180FA005056BB48A4", 
    "ClientMessageType" : "UpdateSalesModelAndVendor", 
    "Sku" : "HBV00000XXXXX", 
    "TraceId" : "EAAB38DD885504F180FA005056BB48A4", 
    "Data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ee2234fde52e50d9520f6d8"), 
            "Sku" : "HBV00000XXXXX", 
            "IsActive" : false, 
            "Version" : NumberInt(1), 
            "CommandName" : "UpdateSalesModelAndVendorCommand", 
            "TraceId" : "EAAB38DD885504F180FA005056BB48A4", 
            "ClientMessageType" : "UpdateSalesModelAndVendor", 
            "ClientMessageId" : "EAAB38DD88551BF180FA005056BB48A4", 
            "ClientUsername" : "USER", 
            "ClientDateTime" : ISODate("2020-06-10T16:38:55.000+0000"), 
            "ReceivedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-10T16:42:23.992+0000"), 
            "InfoMessages" : null, 
            "WarningMessages" : null, 
            "ErrorMessages" : [

            ]
        }
    ], 
    "MessageType" : "Listing.RetailListingCreated", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I have two index like this

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2.0, 
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1.0
        }, 
        "name" : "_id_"
    }, 
    {
        "v" : 2.0, 
        "key" : {
            "Data.Sku" : 1.0
        }, 
        "name" : "Data.Sku_1", 
        "background" : true
    }, 
    {
        "v" : 2.0, 
        "key" : {
            "Data.Sku" : 1.0, 
            "Data.ReceivedAt" : -1.0
        }, 
        "name" : "Data.Sku_1_Data.ReceivedAt_-1", 
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

this query get 0.8 ms (index used)

```
db.eventlogs.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "Data.Sku": -1 } },
    { $unwind: "$Data" },
    { "$skip": 0 }, { "$limit": 50 },
],
    { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

but this query get 2 minutes over ( not index used )

```
db.eventlogs.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "Data.ReceivedAt": -1 } },
    { $unwind: "$Data" },
    { "$skip": 0 }, { "$limit": 50 },
],
    { allowDiskUse: true }
)
```

How can solve this problem. Should i create new index for ReceivedAt ?

db.eventlogs.createIndex( {  "Data.ReceivedAt": -1}, { "background": true});

Comment: Creating an index on `"Data.ReceivedAt"` will solve your issue. You can also verify the usage of index in your query/sort by generating a _query plan_ using the `explain()` method on the aggregation query.

Comment: when i want to use this query "$match Data.Sku" and "$sort Data.ReceivedAt" two index enough ? Should i drop this index {"Data.Sku" : 1.0, "Data.ReceivedAt" : -1.0} @prasad_

Comment: The [db.collection.explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) method output tells which indexes are used when there are multiple indexes on the same fields.

Comment: The query plan has a "winningPlan" document which can have IXSCAN, COLLSCAN and SORT stages - in your case. When an index is used for a query you should see the IXSCAN. And, when an index is used for a sort operation there should NOT be a SORT stage. Finally, when you see COLLSCAN, it means an index is NOT used for a query. This is just a general guideline in your case.

Comment: thank you i created new index for Data.ReceivedAt. Now using index @prasad_